# How can i delete my customer when i pull my row in my recyclerView

Tags: android, viewmodel, instantiation

I have a RecyclerView that I whant to delete a item from in both my database and my UI when I pull on the row of that customer. How do I go about this I have a @Delete function in my DAO that I wanna use and it looks like this

```
@Delete
void deleteOneCustomer(Customer customer);
```

Where do I get my customer that I wanna delete from the RecyclerView? I have a cached customer in my adapter but I do not know how to reach it. This is my adapter...

Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.helper.ItemTouchHelper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomerAdapter.CustomerViewHolder>{

    class CustomerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView name;
        private TextView address;
        private TextView phonenumber;
        private TextView email;


        private CustomerViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameTxt);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
            phonenumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
            email = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addressTxt);
        }
    }

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private List<Customer> mCustomer;

    CustomerAdapter(Context context) { mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context); }

    @Override
    public CustomerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new CustomerViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (mCustomer != null) {
            Customer current = mCustomer.get(position);
            holder.itemView.setTag(current);
            holder.name.setText(current.getFullName());
            holder.address.setText(current.getAddress());
            holder.phonenumber.setText(current.getAddress());
            holder.email.setText(current.getAddress());

        } else {
            holder.name.setText("Full name");
            holder.address.setText("Address");
            holder.phonenumber.setText("Phonenumber");
            holder.email.setText("Email");
        }

    }

    void setCustomer(List<Customer> customers){
        mCustomer = customers;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    // getItemCount() is called many times, and when it is first called,
    // mWords has not been updated (means initially, it's null, and we can't return null).
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (mCustomer != null)
            return mCustomer.size();
        else return 0;
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{




        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        }
    }
}
```

How do I reach this customer so I can delete it? I also have a repository that uses a background thread to run the delete function when you call it. This looks like this

```
private static class deleteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Customer, Void, Void> {

    private CustomerDao mAsyncTaskDao;

    deleteAsyncTask(CustomerDao dao) {
        mAsyncTaskDao = dao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final Customer... params) {
        mAsyncTaskDao.deleteOneCustomer(params[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: the deletion based on what name or id ?

Comment: You can use [ItemClickSupport](https://gist.github.com/nesquena/231e356f372f214c4fe6) on `CustomerAdapter` to get the customer details

Comment: The thing is that I have cached data in this variable    private List<Customer> mCustomer; how van I use this on ItemTouchhelper to be able to delete both the item in recyclerView and in my database?

Comment: Then use `onItemDismiss ()` method which will give you the item position in the adapter based on that retrieve the customer details from the adapter class

Comment: but is the database @Delete set correctly cuz I keep on getting error from the database